# Run time unable to modify default SAPGuiComboBox value in run time BPT framework

Tags: vbscript, uft14

I'm unable to select SAPGuiComboBox value in run time BPT framework. It's highlighted but value is not selected. Always default value is displayed. Unable to modify in run time.
Its modify individual code execution after merging test cases wise its not modify.

```
SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("Konvertering: Test stub").SAPGuiComboBox("AktionKode").Select "OCTOUS"
SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("Konvertering: Test stub").SAPGuiComboBox("AktionKode").Select "#3"
```

Comment: Please format your question as it not readable in the current state.

Comment: Hey Venka :) Read this to learn how to ask your question on Stack --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Unable to modify SAPGuiComboBox default value in run time through UFT in BPT framework.when executed piece of code its updating new value.

Comment: Can some one help me to the above issue.